# Add a new column to graph from secondary query?

Tags: php, mysql

This code works perfect:

```
$grid->addColumn('entity_id', 'Order', 'integer', NULL, false);
$grid->addColumn('customer_firstname', 'Voornaam', 'string');  
$grid->addColumn('customer_email', 'Email', 'string');

$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order ORDER BY entity_id DESC');
$mysqli->close();
$grid->renderXML($result);
```

However I want to add an column called method of payment which uses an other SQL query from other table to get his value/result. I was thinking about this solution :

```
$result2 = $mysqli->query('SELECT  method FROM sales_flat_order_payment');
$grid->renderXML($result+result2);
```

But that idea obvious does not work.

Comment: is there any foreign key between the two tables?

Comment: You should look how to join tables on the same query using `JOIN` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Like guns mentioned you will first need to have a way to connect sales_flat_order_payment with sales_flat_order, then you will have to first add a new column to your grid code and lastly you can do what gbestard suggested, you can run your query with a JOIN get both tables into a single result.

Comment: Yes there is a mutual key, entity_id. I get the idea totally but tried to write the query and it keeps failing. Now reading the mysql documentation ! Thanks everybody..

Comment: Great, if your query keeps failing once you've read how it works, post it and we'll try to help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to make sure the other table has a foreign key that is some how related to the table you want to display the data with.

Then you use a simple `join` on the tables which match the 2 Unique Identifiers from both tables like this:

```
    sql = "SELECT sales_flat_order,
                  sales_payment 
             FROM table_1,
                  table_2 
            WHERE sales_id = sales_payment_id";
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `JOIN` this way to anyone, and much less to someone who wants to learn

Comment: Thanks guys ! This answer works.. @Gbestard, please explain why not and what your solution would be so that Im able to learn it the right way ! Thanks again to everyone..

Comment: If you join tables this way instead of `JOIN table2 ON table1.sales_id = table2.sales_payment_id` it's very easy to miss some conditions, especially when you are joining 4 or more tables in the same query

Comment: But if you do it the second way, and you miss a condition there will be a syntax error and will be by far easier to fix

Comment: It can get a bit complicated if you have a lot of tables that you need to join , another cool way is to use separate queries which work just has well , for learning purposes i suggest you try both methods

Comment: Damn, was partying to early..

$result = $mysqli->query('select * from sales_flat_order,sales_flat_order_payment where entity_id=entity_id');

Produces error : Column 'entity_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Do the tables relate in any way? , try not to use the same primary keys to match each other

Comment: Ok I have chosen for the following option which works.
In order to improve speed of the script I have one last question, is there anyway to just get the column method from the second table (flat_payment) without selecting all columns of the second table.

$result = $mysqli->query('select * from sales_flat_order, sales_flat_order_payment');

Comment: try `$result = $mysqli->query('select * from sales_flat_order sfo ,sales_flat_order_payment sfop where sfo.entity_id=sfop.entity_id');`

Comment: Genious, that solved the ambiguous error ! +1 for you !

Comment: How about if I want to lookup a third table column ? Is it possible ?

Comment: The third table has no entity_id but its called orders_id.